# Lift: How to select a Node in a NodeSeq by attribute and value?

Tags: scala, select, attributes, lift, nodes

I have an NodeSeq object and want to select a given node which is marked with an attribute. For example let's say there is a tag `<div id="content">...</div>` within the NodeSeq.

I tried to select in with the method `\\` on NodeSeq as well as with filter.

Let's say *seq* is my NodeSeq object.

`seq \\ "div"` works, but this selects all `<div>` elements.

`seq.filter(_.attribute("id").equals("content"))` doesn't select any node at all, the resulting list is empty.

How can I select this node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
scala> var x= <b>
 | <h id="bla"/>
 | <h id="blub"/>
 | </b>

x \\ "h" filter (h=>(h \ "@id" toString) == "bla")
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you, this works fine. :-) I am wondering, why it doesn't work with the _.attribute("id").equeals("content") method.

Comment: if you try 
x \\ "h" map (_ \ "@id" )
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[scala.xml.NodeSeq] = List(bla, blub)
the type is NodeSeq so it is not equal to a string ;)

Comment: this is probably nicer:
x \\ "h" map (_ \ "@id" text )
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[String] = List(bla, blub)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could try the following:

```
seq.filter(_.attribute("id").exists(_.text.equals("content")))
```